# How to extract all the rows if a level in one column contains all the levels of another column in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data

```
    ID       INDUSTRY        PRODUCT                  
  625109    PersonalCare     Neolone Preservatives    
  199672    PersonalCare     Neolone Preservatives     
  227047    Pharma           Optiphen
  186117    Food             Sasol BHT
  625109    PersonalCare     Optiphen
  227047    Food             Neolone Preservatives
```

I want to extract rows if an ID contains both the products Neolone Preservatives and Optiphen.

Expected result

```
  ID       INDUSTRY         PRODUCT
 625109    PersonalCare     Neolone Preservatives
 227047    Pharma           Optiphen
 625109    PersonalCare     Optiphen
 227047    Food             Neolone Preservatives
```

The IDs 625109 and 227047 alone contain both the products and hence extracted. How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple ways to do this :

In `dplyr`

```
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   filter(all(c("Neolone Preservatives", "Optiphen") %in% PRODUCT))


#     ID     INDUSTRY               PRODUCT
#   <int>        <chr>                 <chr>
#1 625109 PersonalCare Neolone Preservatives
#2 227047       Pharma              Optiphen
#3 625109 PersonalCare              Optiphen
#4 227047         Food Neolone Preservatives
```

In base R :

```
df[ave(df$PRODUCT, df$ID, FUN = function(x) 
                 all(c("Neolone_Preservatives", "Optiphen") %in% x)) == "TRUE", ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(62, 19, 22, 18, 62, 22),
                 INDUSTRY = c("PC", "PC", "P", "F", "PC", "F"),
                 PRODUCT = c("NP", "NP", "O", "SB", "O", "NP"))

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(any(PRODUCT %in% c("NP"))& any(PRODUCT %in% c("O"))) 

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   ID [2]
     ID INDUSTRY PRODUCT
  <dbl>   <fctr>  <fctr>
1    62       PC      NP
2    22        P       O
3    62       PC       O
4    22        F      NP
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with the library dplyr

```
filteredData<-data %>%
filter(INDUSTRY=='PersonalCare',PRODUCT=='Optiphen')
```